How to marshal all the various ways of installing things under Linux?
~or:~  The Linux equivalent of UniGetUI (née WinGetUI)?
In the world of Linux, there are various ways to install stuff:  "on bare metal" (apt, rpm. etc.), Docker containers, Snaps, Flatpaks, and so on.  Is there a utility that wrangles all these together nicely so I can decide which of these to choose for a given thing I want to install, based on what's available which way (and, ideally, how advisable each choice is)?

Better ask your question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

All !!! You have to be joking, right? The nearest thing you will get is PackageKit. I would never mix & match things to the extents you are asking. I would not even want to mix apt & rpm.

No, a unified software installer does not exist for all POSIX, or even just Linux.  That broad definition doesn't exist on Windows with UniGetUI either, Windows containers are not in scope.
If I am being charitable there are a large number of use cases for installing software. If I am not, developers tend to reinvent the wheel and come up with their own implementation.
Decide what works for your software at your site and limit your efforts to those package managers or distros. Consider software you develop, repackage, or install as-is.

Some package manager categories of my own definition.
Fancy chroots do not bother to coexist with a host OS, which frees them to lay out their files independent of the distro.  Linux containers tend to offer a high degree of isolation.  Snaps and flatpacks less so, such as with desktop applications. Although these are not an OS and rely on lower level software, a kernel, to function.
System packages can build a distro that can boot from (virtual or physical) hardware. dpkg, rpm, opkg, pkgsrc, nix, and so on. Can package basically anything. Convenient to use the same tool for OS and applications. However these need to coexist with the distro, and can break the system without careful use. Which one you use tends to be dictated by which OS distro you prefer: Red Hat/Fedora is rpm, Debian/Ubuntu is dpkg.
Application packages are the remainder of the types of software archives. Usually associated with a language or environment to allow programmers to do proper releases and dependencies.  Pip (Python)  CPAN (Perl).  Independent of the OS, these tend to be safe to give unprivilaged users, and more portable regardless of the distro you are running. Although beware of conflicts with any system packages.

Some high level abstractions exist for installing packages across implementations. Ansible automation's ansible.builtin.package module. PackageKit has pkcon and an API. Both of these do not expose the full functionality.  And don't cover the full range of software archives, notably they are not container tools. Still may be useful in scripts or documentation as a generic way to ensure a thing is installed.
